# Android SQLite: Can I consolidate these four SQLite queries into one?

Tags: sqlite

They're all querying the same table, one SELECTs number of results and the other set of queries SELECTs the minimum.

Can this be conslidated into a single query

```
      likeNewTotal = db.getSingleValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Offers WHERE subCondition = 'likenew'");
   veryGoodTotal = db.getSingleValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Offers WHERE subCondition  = 'verygood'");
 goodTotal = db.getSingleValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Offers WHERE subCondition  = 'good'");
    acceptableTotal = db.getSingleValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Offers WHERE subCondition  = 'acceptable'");

    likeNewLow = db.getSingleValue("SELECT MIN(price) FROM Offers WHERE subCondition = 'likenew'");
        veryGoodLow = db.getSingleValue("SELECT MIN(price) FROM Offers WHERE subCondition  = 'verygood'");
    goodLow = db.getSingleValue("SELECT MIN(price) FROM Offers WHERE subCondition  = 'good'");
    acceptableLow = db.getSingleValue("SELECT MIN(price) FROM Offers WHERE subCondition  = 'acceptable'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the GROUP BY function:

```
SELECT subCondition,COUNT(*),MIN(price) FROM Offers GROUP BY subCondition;
```

This will give you the COUNT(*) and MIN(price) for all distinct values found in `subCondition`.